Cypress. Сравнение двух элементоа
Найдены два элемента и необходимо сравнить содержимое, если не совпадают, то нажать на третий элемент;
если совпадают, то нажать на третий и четвертый элемент и их сравнить


let text1;
cy.get('.card:nth-of-type(1)')
  .click()
  .should('have.class', 'open')
  .then(($first) => {
    text1 = $first.text();
    console.log('text1', text1)
  });

cy.get('.card:nth-of-type(2)')
  .click()
  .should('have.class', 'open')
  .then(($second) => {
    const second = $second.text()
    expect(second, 'second text').to.equal(text1)
  })



Как можно добавить условие в сравнение?
